# Adding up a vector without the sum function

Tags: r

I am trying to learn programming with R.

Can someone show me how to sum this vector without using the function `sum`? This is just an exercise that I am trying to do.

From the package `MASS`, the data `abbey`:

```
[1]   5.2   6.5   6.9   7.0   7.0   7.0   7.4   8.0   8.0   8.0   8.0   8.5   9.0     9.0  10.0  11.0  11.0  12.0
[19]  12.0  13.7  14.0  14.0  14.0  16.0  17.0  17.0  18.0  24.0  28.0  34.0 125.0
```

I would like to sum only the values above the value 10.

So the result should be as it would be with the function `sum`:

```
sum(abbey[abbey>10])

380.7
```

I was trying to do it with the for loop and if else function, and have managed to do this thus far:

```
y= for (i in seq(abey)) {

  if(i>10) { sum(i)} 

}
```

But it returns

```
NULL
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple `for` loop:

```
    Sum<-0
    for (i in abbey) if (i>10) Sum<-Sum+i
    Sum
    #[1] 380.7
```

However, this way can be very slow compared to the `sum` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Yes, the `sum` function is faster, but I wanted to see how it looks the hard way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Reduce` with `+`.

```
Reduce("+", abbey[abbey > 10])
# [1] 380.7
```

Alternatively, you could use the cumulative sum.  This is quite a bit faster than `Reduce`

```
rev(cumsum(abbey[abbey > 10]))[1]
# [1] 380.7
```

Another way would be to use `Recall` in a custom function.  `Recall` *is used as a placeholder for the name of the function in which it is called.* So in this function `mySum`, it sums the values recursively.

```
mySum <- function(x) {
    if(length(x) == 2) { 
        x[1] + x[-1] 
    } 
    else {
        x[1] + Recall(x[-1])
    }
}
mySum(abbey[abbey > 10])
# [1] 380.7
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do an inner product with a vector filled with ones.

```
abbey2 <- abbey[abbey > 10]
as.numeric(t(matrix(abbey2)) %*% rep(1, times = length(abbey2)))
# [1] 380.7
```

Comment: Thank you! Will save it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are into `for` loops (judging by all of your recent questions), `for` loops are "expensive" in R. Instead, you might want to consider checking the *Rcpp* package which allows you writing *efficient* `for` loops in C++ and compile them to R

For example (taken from [Haley's Advaned R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html). (Sorry @Dirk, was too lazy to write it on my own :)))

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('double sumC(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  double total = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    total += x[i];
  }
  return total;
}')

library(MASS)
sumC(abbey[abbey > 10])
## [1] 380.7
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I am into loops now because R is my first programming language that I am learning right now, so I have not yet "got it" how to use them properly.

Comment: Have you tried using `cmpfun` from Prof. Luke Tierney's `compiler` package?

Comment: @Arun, who are you referring to?

Comment: @Arun, no I haven't used it. I'm not sure why are you asking though. Because I said `for` loops are expensive?